# Case statement within a where statement

Tags: sql, case, where-clause

Given a table that contains multiple rows with no primary key like:

```
User         STATE    License
----         -----    -------
User1        FL        aaaaaa
User1        AL        bbbbbb
User2        CO        cccccc
User2        CA        dddddd
User3        GA        eeeeee
User4        NULL      NULL
```

I am trying to write a query that will return the users and licenses for only one state.  The criteria is if the state is CO, then the user and license in the row containing CO as the state is returned.  Otherwise, any one row is sufficient for that particular user.  So for example, I want my output to look something like:

```
User         STATE    License
----         -----    -------
User1        AL        bbbbbb  or     User1        FL        aaaaaa (I don't care)
User2        CO        cccccc
User3        GA        eeeeee
User4        NULL      NULL
```

Edit: I need one row returned per user.  If there is a CO license, I need that to be the returned row, otherwise any row will suffice.  There just needs to be a record returned if that user has at least one entry in the table.

I tried doing something like this, but that did not work.

```
SELECT USER,  
  STATE,  
  LICENSE 
FROM LicenseTable  
Where STATE =   
CASE   
   WHEN state = 'CO' THEN 'CO'  
   ELSE max(state)  
 END
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you elaborate what you are trying to do ? what do you mean by "any one row is sufficient for that particular user"

Comment: @ashish2199 edited for clarification.  I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this query would help you:

```
SELECT top 1 username,state,license FROM LicenseTable where username = 'User1' 
order by case when state='CO' then 0 else 1 end;
```

What we are doing is ordering the result in such a way that when CO is present in the result then we order in such a way that CO comes at top and we display the first record of that result.

[Link to sql fiddle for the same](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/cb987/4)